# Slack Modal submission response to bot's DM not working on different workspace

Tags: ruby, bots, slack, slack-api

I'm working in a slack bot(**scope chat:write, commands, and users:read**), after initiating the bot, a modal opens up, and on submission, the response should be sent to that bot's DM. I'm using **chat.postMessage API** to achieve this(something like this https://api.slack.com/tutorials/message-action). Below is the sample code, this works in a workspace from where I created the bot but when I tried the same on a different workspace in getting `{"ok"=>false, "error"=>"channel_not_found"}`

```
response = JSON.parse(params[:payload])
user_id = response["user"]["id"]
args = {channel: user_id ,text: "A message"} 
@options = { body: args}
HTTParty.post("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage",
  { 
    :body => args.to_json,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer Bot User OAuth Access Token'}
  })
```

What the best way to achieve this? I can't submit it to the app directory because the bot needs to be added in at least two workspaces.

Comment: Plz check whether ur using the right bot token for different workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the problem, I'm passing the bot token of a specific workspace to another workspace. The solution is to store the access_token when the user adds the bot to the workspace and send the access_token when posting the message. Thanks for the tip.[@mothirajha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874794/mothirajha)